# Make background semi-transparent for ajax TabPanel

Tags: html, asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an ASP.NET web application, which has an Ajax Control Toolkit TabContainer on the main page.  I want the TabContainer and child TabPanels to all have a semi-transparent background, so you can see the main page's background image through the TabPanel's backgrounds.

I don't want to just set the opacity because that would make the foreground stuff opaque too.  I don't want to set the TabPanel's background color to Transparent either, because I really want it to be semi-transparent.

I tried using this as a style, but it doesn't seem to work in Chrome or IE.  I think it's CSS 3.0 and maybe not supported? (it shows a CSS 2.0 validation error in Visual Studio)

background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you do this?

```
body>.TabContainer,.TabContainer>.TabPanel{opacity:.5;}
```

Using the `>` selector, this sets the opacity only on .TabContainer and .TabPanel, but none of their child elements.